# How to combine multiple macros and excel functions into a single macro that executes on button click?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to combine multiple macros to a single macro that executes on button click. Kindly excuse me if I write anything wrong since I am completely new to excel macros and vb.

Following is the scenario.

Steps:

1. Calculate total
2. Extract reference
3. Compare total field value for matching reference and mark that as **"Complete"** if sum of total for matching references calculates to ).

***(Explained...)***
First i calculate the debit and credit amount to a new column called total, for this, initially I used the SUM function. after that I tried the same using the macro that executes on button click

***(old macro)***

```
Private Sub getTotal_Click()
    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
For i = 5 To lastRow
    Range("K" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value + Range("G" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

This was so much time consuming (took around 2 hrs when executed on 75k records) than when using the formula (which finished in minutes). I am still not able to understand the reason for this. However modifiying to Dy.Lee's answer below, it took only seconds to calculate the total.

***(modified based on Dy.Lee's answer)***

```
Private Sub getTotal_Click()
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, lastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       vDB = .Range("R5", "S" & lastRow)
       n = UBound(vDB, 1)
       ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 1)
       For i = 1 To n
           vR(i, 1) = vDB(i, 1) + vDB(i, 2)
       Next i
      .Range("AL5").Resize(n) = vR
    End With

End Sub
```

Now moving on to the second macro which I used to extract a pattern from strings in a column D and E.

```
Function extractReference(cid_No As String, pm_source As String)
Dim regExp As Object, findMatches As Object, match As Object
Dim init_result As String: init_result = ""

Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "(?:^|\D)(\d{5,6})(?!\d)"
End With


Set findMatches = regExp.Execute(pm_source)
For Each match In findMatches
    init_result = init_result + match.SubMatches.Item(0)
Next

If init_result <> "" Then
    extractReference = cid_No & " | " & init_result
Else
    extractReference = ""
End If
End Function
```

This macro was working fine.

Finally I used the following function after copying both the extracted reference and total to a new sheet and creating a datatable for that

`=IF(ISBLANK([@Reference]), "", (IF((ROUND(SUMIFS([Total],[Reference],[@Reference]),2)=0), "complete", "")))`

This also worked fine.

Now what I actually want is I need to avoid creating any new data tables or sheets and preform all this within current sheet on a single button click. Is there anyway that can be done without making the macro a time consuming process? Your help is higly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: variant Array explanation is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10717999#10717999)

Answer (score 1):

for the first part try:

```
Private Sub getTotal_Click()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sumRange As Range

    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Set sumRange = Range(Range("K5"), Range("K" & lastRow))
    sumRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]+RC[-4]"
    sumRange.Copy
    sumRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

also, if you still want to loop notice that calling cell like `.Cells(1, 1)` is faster than `Range("A1")`

Comment: Thankyou, I tried the above code but Dy.Lee solution seemed to excecute faster than above.

Comment: quite a suprise, but I did a test and @Dy.Lee code is 9 times faster, so I learned something new today :)

Comment: Defenitely macro is now working really fast. I wanted to upvote more but u are allowed to vote only once. @Dy.Lee if

Answer (score 1):

You need using Variant Array. It is faster.

```
Private Sub getTotal_Click()
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, lastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       vDB = .Range("f5", "g" & lastRow)
        n = UBound(vDB, 1)
        ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To n
            vR(i, 1) = vDB(i, 1) + vDB(i, 2)
        Next i
       .Range("k5").Resize(n) = vR
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou @Dy.Lee its working and very fast. You saved my day!

Comment: What should be done to use the excel formulas with variant?